# Creating a <video> and attaching a media stream to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc

I am making a `WebRTC` application.

Basically I have this code:

```
rtc.onremotestream = function(event) {
    //Want code to create a video tag in a specific <div> and then do this:
    attachMediaStream([THAT NEW VIDEO TAG], event.stream);
}
```

How could I go about doing this? `Autoplay` needs to be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
rtc.onremotestream = function(event) {
  var videoTag = document.createElement('video');
  document.getElementById('specific_div').appendChild(videoTag);
  attachMediaStream(videoTag, event.stream);
}
```

Works?

Comment: attachMediaStream(videoTag , event.stream);

Comment: @MoathHowari Ha! Really!

Comment: @MoathHowari Why did you remove your answer??